# kernel dies after fitting model using fbprophet

Tags: kernel, data-fitting, model-fitting

from fbprophet import Prophet
model = Prophet()
model.fit(data)

*immediately I get the following error*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx4dO.png)

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem. But it works after I follow this steps:

1. Access Anaconda Prompt for the environment that you are working with as admin: `conda remove --force fbprophet`
2. In your jupyter notebook use `pip : install fbprophet`

Answer (score 1):

I had installed fbprophet using the pipe, but it would keep crashing the kernel until I installed it again using the following:

conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet